# Variable number of options for symfony/console component

Tags: php, symfony

How would one configure `symfony/console` to accept a dynamic list of options?

That said - the names for the options aren't known on development step so I need an application to accept everything and expose it using the standard `$input->getOption`.

Any chance it can be done *easily* (without hacking the component in million places)?

My attempts included extending the `ArgvInput` and `InputDefinition` classes but they failed due to various reasons (they are objective and `symfony/console` component implementation-specific). Briefly: the former requires parsing to be invoked multiple times; the latter - is instantiated in multiple places so I just couldn't find a proper way to inject it.

Comment: The various reasons being...

Comment: @webmaster777: it requires knowing the component internals. For the person who knows how it's implemented - they would be obvious, for the person who doesn't - it will take half an hour and references to a lot of files to explain it. I actually started trying it when created a question but then found that I'm falling into meaningless explanations. Provided a brief details though

Comment: So I guess you've tried: but you can't create an override for `InputDefinition::getOption($name)` which doesn't throw an Exception but instead creates the option and `InputDefinition::hasOption($name)` always returning `true` or is there somewhere else being checked whether the option exists?

Comment: @webmaster777: as I mentioned - I couldn't inject `InputDefinition` properly since it's being instantiated internally as well (ie: https://github.com/symfony/Console/blob/master/Command/Command.php#L59). But - yep, it was my original idea.

Comment: So, you don't want to create a custom `Command`, in which you could overload the constructor.

Comment: @webmaster777: it's just one place. I remember there were multiple. And I'm looking for something that wouldn't require extend dozens of classes (if it's possible). PS: even if I extend a command class - it would be tricky to pass the required instance there (since commands are instantiated by an `Application` class internally as well)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47800/discussion-between-webmaster777-and-zerkms)

Comment: @webmaster777: If I create a `ArgvInput` with a custom definition in a `console/app` - it immediately starts validating input - and fails because the default arguments (for a command name) aren't set yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own ArgvInput that will allow all options.

For example you can see the slightly modified version of ArgvInput [here](http://pastebin.com/Rq9fYeG8)

I have only modified lines : 178

And comment out the lines: 188-199

Then pass instance of your version ArgvInput instead of default one to

```
$input = new AcceptAllArgvInput();    
$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->run($input);
```

Comment: For exemplary implementation of this solution, check [LiberalFormatArgvInput](https://github.com/apigen/apigen/commit/c1747ba88767cc2be669702730d05589f7e9fb62)

Answer (score 4):

I have accomplished this in the past using the IS_ARRAY option. Would this not work for your instance as well?

```
->addArgument('routeParams', InputArgument::IS_ARRAY, "Required Placeholders for route");
```

My use case was a custom URL generator for a special authentication system. I needed a way to generate URLs for testing. Naturally, each route has a different number of required parameters and I wanted to avoid passing the parameters as a CSV string.

Command examples:
     Usage: myGenerateToken user route [variables1] ... [variablesN]

```
 php app/console myGenerateToken 1 productHomePage
 php app/console myGenerateToken 1 getProduct 1
 php app/console myGenerateToken 1 getProductFile 1 changelog
```

The variables were delivered to the command in the "routeParams" as an array

```
 $params = $input->getArgument('routeParams');
 var_dump($params);

 array(2) {
   [0] =>
   string(1) "1"
   [1] =>
   string(9) "changelog"
 }
```

I noticed that there is also an "Option" version called `InputOption::VALUE_IS_ARRAY`, but I did not have success getting it to work. The argument version `InputArgument::IS_ARRAY` seems to behave as an option anyways, as it does not error if no arguments are specified.

EDIT:

The author's question is seeking "How do i define variable command line options at run time" where my answer is "How do you provide multiple values for a pre-defined option/argument"

Comment: They are arguments, not options. This might work in some cases, not for this particular one. +1 though :-)

Comment: Oh, i think i see the distinction. You're saying that you need a console command that has a variable array of acceptible options (--dry-run, --name=name, --round=4, etc), depending on runtime conditions?

Comment: Yep. The command works with some kind of templates (which are determined in runtime) and I wanted the values for them to be passed as options. But as I mentioned - your answer might be helpful to someone so please don't drop it :-)

Comment: I see. Yes, i figured as much because i found your question while researching my answer, so i figured others might have the same confusion, but given that my answer was wrong, i also wanted to document my confusion so others would know why my answer didn't apply :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to implement this on PHP 7+ using symfony/console ^3.0:

```
abstract class CommandWithDynamicOptions extends Command {

    /** @var array The list of dynamic options passed to the command */
    protected $dynamicOptions = [];

  /**
   * @inheritdoc
   */
  protected function configure() {
    $this->setName('custom:command');

    $this->setDefinition(new class($this->getDefinition(), $this->dynamicOptions) extends InputDefinition {
      protected $dynamicOptions = [];

      public function __construct(InputDefinition $definition, array &$dynamicOptions) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setArguments($definition->getArguments());
        $this->setOptions($definition->getOptions());
        $this->dynamicOptions =& $dynamicOptions;
      }

      public function getOption($name) {
        if (!parent::hasOption($name)) {
          $this->addOption(new InputOption($name, null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL));
          $this->dynamicOptions[] = $name;
        }
        return parent::getOption($name);
      }

      public function hasOption($name) {
        return TRUE;
      }

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach bypassing Symfony validation and reading from `argv` directly:

```php
class Foo extends Command {
    protected function configure() {
        $this->ignoreValidationErrors();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int {
        global $argv;

        $customOptions = array_filter($argv, static function ($value) {
            return is_string($value) && substr($value, 0, 2) === '--';
        });

        var_dump($customOptions);
    }
}
```

```
./foo --foo=bar

Result:

array(1) {
  [4]=> string(9) "--foo=bar"
}
```