# Make a symfony/console command accept key=value arguments

Tags: symfony, console, symfony-components

I want to use the Symfony console component to make a command like this:

`app/console config:set someConfigName=someValue anotherConfig=anotherValue`

I found this question: [Variable number of options for symfony/console component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866901/variable-number-of-options-for-symfony-console-component)

But it seems unmaintainable to hack ArgvInput and pass it to $app->run(). I'd have to also hack ArrayInput and StringInput, in order to do unit testing, and I'm not sure I'd be able to inject them in the test.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is some kind of [developer experience](http://symfony.com/blog/making-the-symfony-experience-exceptional) and is be worth to [create a feature request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues?labels=DX&page=1&state=open) :)

Comment: you dont wanna use the `InputOption`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel kind of silly about this. :-)

Arguments are always a space-delimited string, and `key=value` looks like a space-delimited string. Explode the string with = as the delimiter, and you have the key and the value.

Comment: For exemplary implementation of this solution, check [LiberalFormatArgvInput](https://github.com/apigen/apigen/commit/c1747ba88767cc2be669702730d05589f7e9fb62)

Comment: @TomášVotruba This is nice - consider a PR to Console Component?

Comment: @calumbrodie Not really motivated. But if you propose issue and it get's accepted, I can handle it.